# adb is stuck when trying to access logs or opening monitor

Tags: android, adb

`adb` used to work fine in my machine, but recently while testing I had to increase the log buffer size using `adb logcat -G 100M` which worked fine. But after few days, now my `adb` is stuck completely. When I run `adb logcat`, it is completely stuck and doesn't do anything.

Things I have tried:

1. Restart adb server
2. Reconnect device (`adb reconnect`)
3. Restart machine
4. Restart android studio.

Btw `adb devices` and `adb shell` works fine. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked when I restarted my phone :)